# first attempt at a sproc transaction

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to write a sproc with a transaction.  Can anybody tell me if there would be any issues with code below, or if it will work as intended?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[DeleteMetricMeter]

(
    @SectionID int,
    @MetricMeterID int,
    @Result bit output
)

as

declare @MetricMeterCount int
declare @err int
declare @rowcount int

set xact_abort on

begin tran

select @MetricMeterCount = count(*) from luMetricMeters
where fkSectionID = @SectionID

select @err = @@error, @rowcount = @@rowcount 

if (@err <> 0) or (@rowcount = 0)
begin
    goto on_error           
end

delete from luMetricMeterList
where pkMetricMeterID = @MetricMeterID

select @err = @@error, @rowcount = @@rowcount 

if (@err <> 0) or (@rowcount = 0)
begin
    goto on_error           
end 

delete from luMetricMeters
where pkMetricMeterID = @MetricMeterID

select @err = @@error, @rowcount = @@rowcount 

if (@err <> 0) or (@rowcount = 0)
begin
    goto on_error           
end

if (@MetricMeterCount = 1)
begin
    delete from luMetricSections
    where pkSectionID = @SectionID

    select @err = @@error, @rowcount = @@rowcount 

    if (@err <> 0) or (@rowcount = 0)
    begin
        goto on_error           
    end
end

commit tran
set @result = 1
return @result

on_error:
    rollback tran
    set @result = 0
    return @result
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the procedure:

- You should not evaluate rowcount unless it really indicates an error. When there is no data deleted there is no need to rollback.
- Your code is not thread safe. The MetricMeterCount query should be changed to this to prevent other threads from performing the delete in between your select & the execution of the delete:

  ```
  select @MetricMeterCount = count(*) 
    from luMetricMeters with (xlock, serializable)
   where fkSectionID = @SectionID
  ```

I would write the code like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[DeleteMetricMeter]

(
    @SectionID int,
    @MetricMeterID int,
    @Result bit output
)

as

DECLARE @MetricMeterCount int
DECLARE @err int
DECLARE @rowcount int

SET xact_abort ON

BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM luMetricMeterList 
 WHERE pkMetricMeterID = @MetricMeterID

SELECT @err = @@error

IF (@err <> 0) 
    GOTO on_error           

DELETE FROM luMetricMeters
 WHERE pkMetricMeterID = @MetricMeterID

SELECT @err = @@error

IF (@err <> 0) 
    GOTO on_error           

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM luMetricMeters WITH (xlock, serializable) 
            WHERE fkSectionID = @SectionID)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM luMetricSections 
     WHERE pkSectionID = @SectionID

    SELECT @err = @@error
    IF (@err <> 0) 
        GOTO on_error           
END

COMMIT TRAN

RETURN (0)

on_error:
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN (-1)
GO
```

Note: The return values should be 0 for success and a negative number for failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sql Server 2005+, I would recomend rather using [TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and have a look at section [*B. Using TRY…CATCH in a transaction*]

This will **GREATLY** simplify your procedure.